# I want my Nexus repo to mirror snapshot of another Nexus repo for 24 hour

Tags: maven, nexus

I am working on the same code as my client but I can not share its SVN server. That's why I've made a bridge with git-svn between our SVN servers to keep code in sync. For some reason I can make this synchronisation automaticaly only once a day, let's say at 3 o'clock in the morning. This part works (almost) right.

I also have a Nexus repository that is the mirror of my client's Nexus repo. The code depends on a lot of others artifacts from my client, all in a SNAPSHOT version. Very often, the API of one of these dependencies changes, and a new artifact is available on my client's Nexus repo. When I compile locally, maven checks for new version of dependencies, finds the new artifact with the new API, downloads it, and uses it for compilation. Since my code is only synchronized once a day, I don't have the latest code version, and my local code does not compile any more. There is a temporal inconsistency between the code and the Nexus.

To resolve that, I would like my local Nexus repo not to check for new versions from its parent. That is my problem, I don't know how to do that.

My solution so far was to :

- expire the cache of my local Nexus repo at 3 oclock (with a Nexus
  scheduled task)
- set the cache artifact max age to 1440 min (24 hours)
  so that the repo will consider that the cache is OK until the next
  SVN synchro
- set the metadata Max age to 1440 min too, so that my repo
  won't consider rechecking metadata on the parent repo

This is where my knowledges led me but seemingly this is not correct, since when I compile with the -U option, my local repo still keeps on rechecking its parent for new versions.

Can someone tell me where I am wrong? Is there something to do with the Index too ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was good : with this policy, I can have a snapshot of my client's repo for 24 hour. And to be sure that all the artefacts on **my** repo are temporally consistent, i've added a daily job that downloads **all** the dependencies i need for my day of work, all at once. This job simply executes the *go-offline* goal of the *dependency* plugin of maven, just after the *expire cache*.

Why I posted here was wrong behaviors of my repo, but the source of these mistakes was not the Nexus cache mechanism, but the *routing* mechanism. Indeed, **my** repo is a proxy repo of **the client's** repo, which is of type *group*. I've figured out in the Nexus documentation that the *routing* mechanism can not work for repo of type *group*.
I deactivated the routing and all goes fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The snapshots downloaded are determined by the maven-metadata.xml files, so if you need the latest snapshots as soon as they are published you need to set the metadata max age for the snapshot proxy repository to zero.

If you're using Nexus Professional you can avoid the overhead of a zero cache timeout by using its smart proxy feature:

http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/_introduction_3.html

Comment: Maybe my explanation was not clear. I do not want to get the last version published, i want to get the version published just after 3 o'clock in the morning. I should have specify :
`To resolve that, I would like my local Nexus repo not to check for new versions from its parent... **for a 24 hour period**`
That's why I fixed the delays to 1440 min.